# Limit packet size with iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to make a packet size limit on all ports (tcp and udp) for incoming connections with iptables so that it does not exceed 1500 bytes. If this rule is violated, then the IP from which the packet was sent is blocked. This is how I hope to protect myself from DDOS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you have asked (change the interface name for your computer):

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat length-limit
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# length-limit 2022.08.07 Ver:0.01
#       test packet length syntax
#       For a test.
#       see also ask 1422353.
#
echo "length-limit packets. $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

# Set some stuff
# Adjust these values for your system.
#
EXTIF="br0"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
LAN="192.168.111.0/24"

# Clear old INPUT table rules
#
$IPTABLES -F INPUT

# Check the BAD GUY list for already banned IPs:
# Use a short timeout for testing, but suggest longer for real use.
# Consider using a bit mask here, as often bad guys just move to a different IP on the same subnet.
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 30 --name BADGUY_LONG -j DROP

# Not sure the max payload length, but it is 16 bits, so try 65535.
# And if one tries 65536 the below error is generated:
# iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): length: bad value for option "--length" near "65536", or out of range (0-65535).
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m length --length 1500:65535 -m recent --set --name BADGUY_LONG -j DROP
```

It results in this:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       3     4498 DROP       all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 1 name: BADGUY_LONG side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
       1     1500 DROP       all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            length 1500:65535 recent: SET name: BADGUY_LONG side: source mask: 255.255.255.255

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And I tested it with these commands from another computer:

```
doug@s15:~/diag/tcpdump/captures/035$ ping -c 2 -s 1471 s19
ping: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
PING s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136) 1471(1499) bytes of data.
1479 bytes from s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.545 ms
1479 bytes from s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.575 ms

--- s19.smythies.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.545/0.560/0.575/0.015 ms
doug@s15:~/diag/tcpdump/captures/035$ ping -c 2 -s 1472 s19
ping: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
PING s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136) 1472(1500) bytes of data.

--- s19.smythies.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1014ms

doug@s15:~/diag/tcpdump/captures/035$ ping -c 2 -s 1471 s19
ping: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
PING s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136) 1471(1499) bytes of data.

--- s19.smythies.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1028ms

doug@s15:~/diag/tcpdump/captures/035$ sleep 30
doug@s15:~/diag/tcpdump/captures/035$ ping -c 2 -s 1471 s19
ping: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
PING s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136) 1471(1499) bytes of data.
1479 bytes from s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.573 ms
1479 bytes from s19.smythies.com (192.168.111.136): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.529 ms

--- s19.smythies.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.529/0.551/0.573/0.022 ms
```